# Object doesn't follow path

Tags: animation

Even if I set both origins to the same place, the object still doesn't follow the path but is miles away from it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Back yourself up against unintended side-effects, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Clear Transform Menu > Clear Location. This will land your object's origin on the curve.